# Export blocks with features extra

Tags: drupal-7

I installed the Features extra module to export custom made blocks in my Drupal 7 environment. But for some reason, it doesn't work...

What I do is the following:

1. I create a custom block
2. I give it a machine name, description, title and body, just like it's required.
3. I go to `Structure - features - Create feature`
4. I create my feature by clicking the custom block under `FE Block`
5. The `fe_block` dependencies fills in automatically.
6. I download the feature and place it in `/sites/all/modules/features`
7. In my install profile I add this line: `dependencies[] = custom_blocks`
8. I try to reinstall the website and... nothing!

The blocks aren't showing up in my `Block`-page, but the feature is... What am I doing wrong in this process? Do I need to enable something or install an extra module in order to get my custom blocks exported?

Or is there any other way how to get custom made content in the install profile?

Comment: Please do not cross-post the same question across sites. Ask to have a question migrated if it's not working somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the same theme enabled? The FE_block can only store settings for a block and theme toghter as the region differs between themes.

Comment: It's always the same theme. It are custom blocks within a Homebox-dashboard. So they aren't enables in the Block overview. They just exists and used by the Homebox-module.

Comment: Have you enable the feature? And do you get any "overridden" notification for the featue after enabling it?